# How to start a method after another method is done

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have two timers, a `System.Timers.Timer` and a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Now each 1.5s both are calling a method. But they ain't synchronized because sometimes the method that's called with the `System.Timers.Timer` needs a bit longer till it's done. Is there a way to make the method that's called with `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` wait till the method from `System.Timers.Timer` is done?

What I tried so far:

```
 private void FileReadFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (NetPinger.source.AddGraph b in graphList)
            {
                b.fileRead();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex));
        }
        myTimer.Stop();
        aTimer.Start();
    }

    public void prepData(object objectInfo, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (NetPinger.source.AddGraph b in graphList)
        {
            b.prepareData();
        }
        aTimer.Stop();
        myTimer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Well... why don't you just have a single timer that performs A and calls B afterwards?

Comment: with method A I'm preparing the data and with method B I'm just updating the GUI and WinForms Timer is afaik in the GUI thread and the other not and if I do all the tasks in the winforms timer the gui is performing very poorly.

Comment: Maybe use **[Thread Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/thread-synchronization)**?

Comment: Why don't you create a new function that calls both functions, and call that function using one timer ?

Comment: Use only a System.Timers.Timer and prepare the data evert 1.5 seconds and then updated the UI using Invoke method immediately afterwards, in the same event handler.

Comment: @mm8 thanks sir! it worked out perfecty, can you add it as answer so i can upvote you and mark it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only the `System.Timers.Timer` and prepare the data every 1.5 seconds and then update the UI using `Invoke` method immediately afterwards, in the same event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Timer timer1;
Timer timer2;

private void Timer1_Elapsed()
{
//just to make sure your timer1 & timer2 doesn't fire before you do your work
timer1.Stop();
timer2.Stop();
// Do What you want here
timer2.Start();
}

private void Timer2_Elapsed()
{
timer2.Stop();
//Do what you want here
timer1.Start();
}
```

Just make sure to start your timer1 initially.

Comment: thanks for answer but after one tick, its not going anymore to the next.

Comment: does timer1 and timer2 run atleast once?

Comment: If possible paste the code from inside timer Events

Comment: I did it like this: on button click i start both timers - than in function A: it executes code stops timer A, starts timer B, than in function B: executes the code, stops timer b and starts timer a. It runs one A, than B, than again A but than nothing. I added code in question.

Comment: Stop the timer at the beginning of the method